# How to get audios informations like album name, thumb art, quality, etc

Tags: android, audio-player

I want to create a music player.

My aim is to build some thing similar to that of Google's Google Play Music.

Where should I get audio information like 
songs title,
album name, 
thumb art, 
quality info, etc.?